# How can i make it so that if a progressbars value is 90 or above an event will happen?

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, system

I want it so that if the value of progressbar1 is 90 or above a message box will pop up. How would i do this in VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

you would want to create a custom ProgressBar adding an event that is raised when the bar changes.  Then in your consumption code handle the event checking the value.  This thread has a pretty good example of how to do it.

[forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?449375-RESOLVED-Where-is-progressbar-change-event](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?449375-RESOLVED-Where-is-progressbar-change-event)

I hope this helps!